# Change date format in bash

Tags: bash, date, input, format

I want to take input date as "`2022-08-14T21:56:17+00:00` and want to convert it to format like this "`14/08/2022 9:56:17`"(dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss). how to convert first date format into second format. The input date is taken from the output of the earlier command.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the (GNU) `date` command:

```bash
$ TZ=Europe/UK date -d '2022-08-14T21:56:17+00:00' +"%d/%m/%Y %r"
14/08/2022 09:56:17 μμ
```

You can see how to specify the output format here: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Time-conversion-specifiers.html